# can I use pygame camera and PIL (pillow) together? How?

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

I know you can use PIL to open a file(say jpg) and process it. 
I am also using pygame.camera to obtain a snapshot of the camera

say I have something like

```
cam=pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()
image=cam.get_image()
```

how can I process this `image` with PIL? is it even possible?

I tried

`img_gray=ImageOps.grayscale(image)`

but I got an error saying "Invalid argument specifying new format to convert to" (return image.convert("L")

is there a way to do something like this??

Comment: always put FULL error message (Traceback) in QUESTION.

Comment: PyGame `image` is PyGame's `Surface`, `PIL` may expect PIL's Image object. Both should have functions `to_string`, `from_string`.